# Using mxGetPr vs mxGetData

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to write a simple mex function. I have an integer input which is the number of my objects.
When I compile `myMEX_1.cpp` and call it by MATLAB with any input value, I always get:

> Number of Requested Objects := 0

But the `myMEX_2.cpp` works fine and show the number inputted from MATLAB command window.
Where is the my mistake in `myMEX_1.cpp`?

*My enviroment: MATLAB R2013a and Microsoft SDK 7.1 compiler.*

```
// myMEX_1.cpp
#include "mex.h" 
void mexFunction(int nlhs,       mxArray *plhs[], 
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{

    char str11[100];
    unsigned short frameCount;
    //unsigned short *frameCountPtr;
    frameCount = (*((unsigned short*)mxGetData(prhs[0])));
    sprintf(str11, "Number of Requested Objects := %d:\n", frameCount);
    mexPrintf(str11);
}





// myMEX_2.cpp
#include "mex.h" 
void mexFunction(int nlhs,       mxArray *plhs[], 
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{
   char str11[100];
   unsigned short frameCount;
   double* dblPointer; 
   dblPointer = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
   frameCount = (unsigned short)(*dblPointer);
   sprintf(str11, "Number of Requested Objects := %d:\n", frameCount);
   mexPrintf(str11);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mxGetData`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetdata.html) returns a `void` pointer which must be cast to a pointer of the *correct* datatype.

> In C, `mxGetData` returns a `void` pointer (`void *`). Since `void` pointers point to a value that has no type, **cast the return value to the pointer type that matches the type specified by `pm`**

In your case, I'm assuming that although it looks like you've passed in an integer, it's actually a `double` since that is MATLAB's default datatype so your issue is due to the fact that you try to convert it to an `unsigned short` pointer.

```
myMEX_1(1)          % Passes a double
myMEX_1(uint16(1))  % Passes an integer
```

To fix this, we would need to cast the output of `mxGetData` as a `double` pointer instead, and then dereference it, cast it and assign it

```
frameCount = (unsigned short)*(double*)mxGetData(prhs[0]);
```

[`mxGetPr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetpr.html) is the same as `mxGetData` *except* that it automatically casts the output of `mxGetData` as a `double` pointer. Thus, it saves you a step but is only appropriate for `double` inputs (which you have).

If you want to handle inputs of multiple types appropriately, you'll need to check the type of the input using either [`mxIsDouble`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxisdouble.html) or [`mxIsClass`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxisclass.html).

```
if ( mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) ) {
    frameCount = (unsigned short)*mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
} else if ( mxIsClass(prhs[0], "uint16") {
    frameCount = *(unsigned short*)mxGetData(prhs[0]);
} else {
    mexPrintf("Unknown datatype provided!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: `mxGetPr` always returns `*double` quite independent of the input argument's type.

Comment: @GmtK I thought that but was just checking that out. Although your code works if you *really* pass in an integer: `myMEX_1(uint16(1))`

Comment: The function prototype is presented in MATLAB help as `double *mxGetPr(const mxArray *pm);`

Comment: Nice comment: *Although your code works if you really pass in an integer: `myMEX_1(uint16(1))`*. Yes, It works. Hence it is concluded that MATLAB's default type is `double` for my integer input. Is it correct?

Comment: MATLAB help recommends: Use `mxGetPr` on arrays of type double only. Use `mxIsDouble` to validate the `mxArray` type. For other `mxArray` types, use `mxGetData`. What is the reason for it?

Comment: @GmtK I have updated my answer to be a little clearer and show an example of when and how to use `mxGetData`.